# Load json in UITableview Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I want to display my json file from a server in a UITableview. I have the part where i get the json from the web but i don't know how to put it in a table. Can somebody help me with some tips.

Here is my Json

```
{ "Food": [ { "title": "Botherham", "speaker": "Jason Shapiro" }, { "title": "Ei", "speaker": "Jim White" } ], "IDK NOTHING": [ { "title": "Botherham" }, { "title": "Ei" } ] }
```

And here is my objective code of how i get my json from the web

```
#import "ViewControllerLogin.h"

@implementation ViewControllerLogin

@synthesize userName;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
    self.title = userName;




    NSData *allCoursesData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                              [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.11:8888/swift/asortiment.php"]];

    NSError *error;

    NSMutableDictionary *allCourses = [NSJSONSerialization
                                       JSONObjectWithData:allCoursesData
                                       options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                       error:&error];


    if( error )
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else {
        NSArray *Food = allCourses[@"Food"];
        for ( NSDictionary *theCourse in Food )
        {
            NSLog(@"Title: %@", theCourse[@"title"] );
            NSLog(@"----");
        }
    }





}

@end
```

Comment: Do you know how to use a table view and provide it data in general?

Comment: No i don't know how to do it

Comment: Then start by reading the "Table View Programming Guide for iOS" in the docs.

Comment: For better understanding , follow this tutorial :http://nscookbook.com/2013/03/ios-programming-recipe-16-populating-a-uitableview-with-data-from-the-web/